# How to reload file_snapshot in SymmetricDS

Tags: symmetricds

I have a filesync configured in a one way direction and suddenly all the records of the 'sym_file_snapshot' table have been deleted. Well, what i'd like to know is if there is a way to reload this table without to send all the files to clients again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without a deep knowledge in symmetricDs I wouldn't recommend manual update of this and other `sym_*` tables. `touch` all files that are under file synchronization, let them have synced to targets, wait a bit and everything should be fine.

Comment: Yes, I agree with not updating manually those sym_* tables. I don't want to touch all files to avoid sending all (they are more than 30k - about 3GB of data through internet). I think i have to drop and create the file syncing again, marking not to make initial loading. Thanks for replying.

Comment: that's not a bad idea